# Media queries not working

Tags: css, media-queries

My CSS that uses media queries doesn't detect devices correctly...
My code:

```
@media  screen and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 320px) {
    #test{
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:blue;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
    #test{
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```

I want the div to be blue on a small phone like HTC wildfire and red on a tablet like iPad Mini.

Comment: You can specify `screen` after `@media screen and`

Comment: Passerby I did it that way. But i get an blue div also on the smaller device!

Comment: Browsers on small device tend to scale up a little bit by default. You may need to also specify `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />` on your pages to trigger the "real" dimension. To debug, inspect `document.body.getBoundingClientRect()` to see the "rendered" dimension of your pages.

Comment: Can you provide relevant html? Maybe in a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: '<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />'
This did the trick!

Comment: @Passerby, post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Extending from comment:

Browsers on small devices tend to scale web pages a little bit. To get the "real" dimension for media queries, add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
```

to the head of your document.

To inspect the "rendered" dimension, use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    var box=document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
    document.getElementById("whatever").value=box.width+" x "+box.height;
},false);
</script>
```

This may or may not prevent the scale setting of the browser itself, but will at least prevent the "auto" scaling.

In my own experience, some situations, like a `<p>` with long sentence, will likely causes browsers to scale down to make it more feel like "a sentence". By specifying `initial-scale=1.0`, Opera Mobile still scale to its setting (by default 125%), but no more than that, and the long sentence will wrap.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with adding screen to the query.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 240px) {
    #test{
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:blue;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
    #test{
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```